# Line number with comm command. Is it possible?

Tags: bash, awk, compare, comm

I compare two files with this command

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

It works perfectly and says me differences. But I would like to show me also the line number (lines unique in second file).

file1:

```
a
d
e
f
g
```

file2:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I do:

```
 comm -13 file1 file2
```

Output

```
b
c
```

But I need the line numbers where b and c are in file2, desired output:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a){print FNR}' file1  file2
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

**Edit:** As presented in the OP, the `comm` behaves differently when file `file2` has duplicates. Below solution should fix that (see comments and thanks @EdMorton):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]++
    next
}
{
    if(!($0 in a)||a[$0]<=0)
        print FNR
    else a[$0]--
}' file1 file2
```

Output now (`file2` has a duplicate entry `d` where `FNR==5`):

```
2
3
5
```

Hopefully there aren't that many more pitfalls waiting...

Comment: That's not quite the same. Add a 2nd `d` line to file `a` then try `comm -13 b a`  and your awk command and you'll find the former correctly outputs `d` while the latter doesn't output the line number that'd be associated with `d` because it doesn't take duplicates into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next} (--a[$0]) < 0{print FNR}' file1 file2
```

e.g. Using a modified `file2` that includes an extra `d` line to prove that duplicate values are handled correctly:

```
$ cat file2
a
b
c
d
d
e
```

```
$ comm -13 file1 file2
b
c
d
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next} (--a[$0]) < 0' file1 file2
b
c
d
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++; next} (--a[$0]) < 0{print FNR}' file1 file2
2
3
5
```